# What is the default method for printing an environment variable in R?

Tags: r, scoping

If I take `e <- environment()` and I call `print(e)` or just `e`, I get

```
> e
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

But `e` has NULL attributes, and has named elements accessible by `$` based on hidden and findable objects in the workspace of that environment (included by default .N and .RandomSeed).

There is no method for `print.environment`. How does R know to print `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`?

I would like to be able to make a `print.environment` method that works along the lines of:

```
print.environment <- function(env) {
  paste('We are in', as.character(env))
}
```

And would like to avoid `capture.output`. Where is the actual name that is printed to the shell stored in the environment object?

Comment: Hi!, check that: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.getenv.html hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

`print.default` handles that.

You could try:

```
print.environment <- function(x, ...) cat("We are in", environmentName(x), "\n")

# test
e <- new.env()
attr(e, "name") <- "X"
print(e)
## We are in X
```

If that is not adequate then at the R level (as opposed to the C level) I think you will need to use `capture.output` .  This prints out the hash and if there is a name, the name too.

```
print.environment <- function(x, ...) {
  h <- gsub("^<environment: |>$", "", grep("<environment: ", 
         capture.output(print.default(x)), value = TRUE))
  Name <- environmentName(x)
  if (h == Name) h <- ""
  Name <- if (Name != "") paste0("(", Name, ")")
  cat("We are in", h, Name, "\n")
}

e <- new.env()
print(e)
## We are in 0x000000000d3e6fa8 

attr(e, "name") <- "X"
print(e)
## We are in 0x000000000d3e6fa8 (X) 

print(.GlobalEnv)
## We are in  (R_GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hmm... but it is blank when I do this inside a function. If I say `print(environment)` inside a function, it shows a... signed byte code (correct me if wrong terminology here), something like: ` <environment: 0x000000002f13fb50>`

Comment: The code shown gives "" if the environment is not named.

Comment: Is it possible to recover the gobbledy-gook as a character to demonstrate that the function is somehow in a new, albeit temporary, environment?

Comment: I have added an example showing the adding of an environment name and then printing the environment.  is that sufficient for what you need?

Answer (score 0):

One can access the environment's name using `environmentName` as in the following example:

```
> e <- environment()
> paste("You are in the enviroment: ",environmentName(e))
[1] "You are in the enviroment:  R_GlobalEnv"
```